# How to make a runnable jar of my maven project?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, manifest.mf

I want to make a jar file of my project but it shows error when I try to make jar.

**Till now**, I build a jar that is executed by using a command ,

`java -cp <JAR FILE> <MAIN CLASS NAME>`.

I have done this by adding plugin in the POM,

```
<plugin> 
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
<configuration> 
<descriptorRefs> 
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> 
</descriptorRefs> 
</configuration> 
</plugin>
```

and by running command , `mvn clean` and `mvn install assembly:assembly`.

**But I want** a jar, that will run by using command `java -jar <JAR FILE>`

For that I read [this link](http://www.itcuties.com/tools/maven-custom-manifest-file/) and implemented also. But it shows below error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on project ThreadPool: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar for parameter manifest: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.archiver.ManifestConfiguration for 'addClassPath' -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me making jar file, that executes by using `java -jar` command.
Thanks in advance . Looking for your kind response.

**EDIT NO 1**

I added below plugins, dependency in POM,

```
<!-- Example dependency -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>your.fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

this will add

```
Main-Class: your.fully.qualified.MainClass
```

header to jars's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and make it runnable

You can run maven build as one line

```
mvn clean package assembly:single
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that somewhere in your pom.xml file you have an element ClassPath that is not understood by the element you are configuring. Search for that and see if it makes sense.

Comment: I added the dependency , that I addedin POM, please see in EDIT  NO. 1. ANd where I add MainClassPath, that you said in your answer ??

Comment: The above dependency gives the error tat I mentioned in the question.